# Where is the source code from the WCH RISC-V toolchain?

Tags: embedded, riscv, toolchain, gnu-toolchain, riscv32

WCH, the company behind the famous 10-cent RISC-V microcontroller, has based its RISC-V toolchain on the xPack builds from Liviu Ionescu:
https://github.com/xpack-dev-tools/riscv-none-embed-gcc-xpack/releases/tag/v8.2.0-3.1/

Both output the same version string:

```bash
riscv-none-embed-gcc.exe (xPack GNU RISC-V Embedded GCC, 32-bit) 8.2.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

However, there are some minor differences between the RISC-V toolchain from WCH and the one from xPack. The WCH toolchain supports a few more RISC-V instruction sets, like:

- `rv32ecwx`
- `rv32imacxw`
- `rv32imafcxw`

**Question 1:**
The `'w'` and `'x'` letters are non-standard RISC-V extensions. What do they stand for?

I also notice that the WCH toolchain has the following libraries that don't appear anywhere in the native xPack toolchain:

- `libIQMath_RV32.a`
- `libprintf.a`
- `libprintfloat.a`

**Question 2:**
What are these non-standard libraries for? I was able to build a sample project with both the WCH toolchain and the native xPack toolchain. In both cases, the `printf()` function worked just fine, sending characters over the `TX` line. So I wonder what the `libprintf.a` library is used for, if the setup works without that library?

**Question 3:**
Where can I find the source code of the WCH toolchain, and the build instructions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a "Source code.zip" file in the github repo you linked. Maybe that is what you need.

Comment: Yeah, but that's for the native xPack toolchain. I need the source code (and build instructions) from the WCH toolchain.

Comment: Whoever gave you the WCH toolchain has to give you the source code if it is GPL. You may have to ask them, since technically they only need to offer to give the source on request.

Comment: You are advised to post _single_ questions on SO - then you can get complete answers from users who may not know the answer to _all_ your questions.  Question 3 is in any case off-topic.

Comment: Hi @pmacfarlane , thank you for this insight. Is it only on request? Where did you read that?

Comment: It's in section 3 of the [GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html). They have to give you the source, or offer to give you it.

Comment: I can confirm that they (WCH/MRS) have made modifications to the GPL covered source, created binary's, and released the binary's for public consumption. They are required under the terms of the GPL to release the source that they use *verbatim* to produced said binary's upon request. The source code linked in the question is what they TOOK, not what they made. Unfortunately, the GPL is rarely enforceable in the PRC.

Answer (score 1):

### A1:

From page 2, Chapter 1.1 of the QingKeV2 Processor Manual (note that "V2A" is the WCH designation for their RTL realization of the RISC-V ISA used in the CH32V003)

> - XW: 16-bit compression instruction for self-extending byte and half-word operations
>   *Note: To further improve code density, extend the XW subset by adding the following compression directives
>   c.lbu/c.lhu/c.sb/c.sh/c.lbusp/ c.lhusp/c.sbsp/c.shsp, use based on the MRS compiler or the toolchain it provides.*

Note: *Something not mentioned in your question, that is modified behavior from the link, is the fact that the CH32V family (being microcontrolers) have optimized interrupt hardware that has integrated CPU/compiler support. Particularly, they have a fast call scheme that shadows critical registers when a call is invoked. This reduces latency because it does not have to push return addresses to the stack. Useful for real time applications.*

### A2:

The first library is an RV optimized math library. It is essentially a float-fixed implementation that provides some interchange between the two. It is "inspired by" Texas Instruments® C28x IQmath Library.

Near as I can tell, the other two of those libraries separate out integer and floating point from the original routine. This makes `printf()` lighter for most tasks... unless you need to use the `%f` feature. (You should note that, although it compiles and works mostly as expected, specifically `%f` does not actually work.)

### A3:

This is the real issue. Indeed, the source project that WCH used is covered under the GPL. Indeed, WCH/MRS took that source, modified it, and released the product binary. Under the GPL, they should be compelled to provide the source upon request under the protections of the license.

I am not an authority on the PRC, so I can't say with certainty what the GPL license means to them. However, a quick search on the web suggests "not much."